# vb.net Using Invoke on main thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I can use the following from another thread to execute the containing code on the main thread.

```
Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                             Main Thread Code
                         End Sub))
```

I have a function that may or may not be called from the main thread, if it isnt then the invoke needs to be used. What would happen if I make it so that function always uses an invoke whether its run on the main thread or not? Would there be any negative effects?

Comment: `Invoke` is not a feature inherent in the VB.NET programming language. Are you talking about Windows Forms? (If so, then calling `Invoke` even if it isn't necessary might be slightly inefficient, but shouldn't cause any problems. I could well imagine that it internally runs a `InvokeRequired` check.)

Comment: There's a wee bit of overhead, nothing to worry about.  The bigger issue is you using Invoke(), it should only ever be used when you need the return value of a method you call.  Not the case here, always use BeginInvoke() instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about not just calling `Invoke` but rather only calling `Invoke` if `InvokeRequired` is `True`?

```
Dim method As New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                    'Main thread code
                                End Sub)

If InvokeRequired Then
    Invoke(method)
Else
    method()
End If
```